# Vb excel loop not updating

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and what I try to do is basically collect data and locate that data in a cell starting from `A1` up to `A100` the data comes from cell `M4` this particular cell is dynamic and is constantly changing it's value, is Pulling data from `DDE`
the code works but for some reason it takes the first value and does not update as the `M4` is changing.

Any Ideas?

```
Sub looptest()

Dim loop_ctr As Integer

For loop_ctr = 1 To 100

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & loop_ctr).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M4")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Next loop_ctr

MsgBox " Done! "

End Sub
```

Comment: How does `M4`'s value change? Are you sure that `M4`'s value is actually changing?

Comment: Your loop as I read it cycles through `A1` to `A100` and changes the value of those cells to equal the value of `M4`. Maybe to loop every time `M4` changes you could call it from a worksheet change event. But that could cause some issues. Also, I don't understand the need for the `Wait` command, can you expound on that?

Comment: during runtime your macro evaluate the current value of `M4` and not the value it will be when it updates. so this won't work. yes you can set up an event that will trigger when value in `M4` updates as what @guitarthrower mentioned.

Comment: HI the M4 value changes because is linked to a DDE server, and is a value that I want to read every second and then create a chart with the behavior of that value, the issue is, the macro captures the current value in that M4 cell and continues changing the value to the rest of the cells with that particular number instead of using the most current value

Answer (score 0):

After `Application.Wait ...` line try adding:

```
DoEvents
```

As written, you code doesn't expose Excel to any other system events, like your DDE, to update the Excel application for the entire 100 second execution time of your loop.